# How do i access each character individually in a string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

In this i need to take in a user imputed sentence and print it out in pig-latin.
(also i have several imports that aren't needed but I left them in when i copied the class and main lines from another program)

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Pig_latin
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

    String sentence;

    out.print("Enter a complete sentence: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    sentence=sc.nextLine();
```

Here i am creating the string array and splitting at the spaces.
The only problem with this is that now each word is in its own object.

```
    String s1[]=sentence.split(" ");
```

Because I've separated the words I don't know of a way to access each character to move them to the end or add "ay".

```
    for(int x=0;x<s1.length;x++)
    {

    }
}   
}
```

Comment: `s1[x]` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a simple way of how you can get each character in a string in java. `String.charAt(index)` gets the current character at the index specified.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String getMyCharacters = "Hello World";

        for(int i = 0; i < getMyCharacters.length();i++)
        {
            System.out.print(getMyCharacters.charAt(i));
        }

}

output: Hello World
```

And this is one way of how you get the characters when you split each word into its own string.

```
String[] splitted = getMyCharacters.split(" ");


for(int j = 0; j < splitted.length; j++)
{
    System.out.println("\nCurrent word:" + splitted[j]);
    for(int y = 0; y < splitted[j].length(); y++)
    {
        System.out.println(splitted[j].charAt(y));
    }
}

output:
Current word:Hello
H
e
l
l
o

Current word:World
W
o
r
l
d
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer each element of the array with `s1[x]`, x is the index of the array s1, thereby saying you are looking up the xth element of the array.

```
 for(int x=0;x<s1.length;x++)
{
  System.out.println(s1[x]);
}
```